# Select dropdown list - R Selenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select a dropdown with some options useing R selenium.

Here is the code from the website

[image: 1]

I am trying to select the option "all". I created that option on the website. I cant select that option allthogh I can select the other. Do I use xpath?

Regards

I have managed to select the original option but not the one I created myself.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML and properly format it instead. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. What do you mean you "created" the "all" option on the website?

Answer (score 0):

To identify the element with text as ***all*** you can use the following line of code:

```
option_all <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "div.Select-control span.Select-value-label[id^='react-select'] div")
```